# Error in Pydub after compiling to exe

Tags: python

My code runs successfully on my editor 'SCITE' but after compiling to an executable file, it says

> Import Error: no module name pydub

What causes this error?  How do I debug this error?

I know that I already installed pydub and tried testing it using this code with no errors.

```
from pydub import AudioSegment
```

This is the code I am using to compile my python code.

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe, sys, os

sys.argv.append('py2exe')

setup(
        options = { 'py2exe': {'bundle_files': 1,"includes":["sip"]}},
        windows = [{'script': "converter.py"}], 
        zipfile = None,
        )
```

Comment: Hey there, are you using Python 3 when you compile? It's likely that `pydub` was only installed for Python 3.x on your machine.

Comment: hi thanks for the reply. i am using python 2.5.4 when compiling. should i update to python 3?